# Only allow pinging in one direction

Tags: firewall, ping, icmp, mikrotik-routeros

How do I allow a ping from the first PC to a second one but block a ping from the second PC to the first one?

I created this firewall rule on both Mikrotik routers:

```
add action=accept chain=forward dst-address=192.168.100.17 protocol=icmp \
    src-address=192.168.11.252
add action=accept chain=forward dst-address=192.168.11.252 protocol=icmp \
    src-address=192.168.100.17
add action=drop chain=forward
```

If I turn off the first or second rule, none of the pings work. If I allow both, pinging works on both PCs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both 'ping' requests *and* responses are ICMP. So one rule allows the request and another allows the response, in either direction.

You can match individual ICMP packet types using `icmp-options=Type[:Code]`. According to [this website](http://shouldiblockicmp.com/), echo requests are type 8 and responses are type 0.

Note that ICMP is *a bit more* than just 'ping'. It is really not wise to discard ICMP error indications.

Comment: Thx. It seems to be helped. I know the importance of ICMP, but for now, this was a goal.

Answer (score 2):

For those who need an answer:

On both routers I matched ICMP type 0 (echo reply) to rule:

```
add action=accept chain=forward dst-address=192.168.100.17 protocol=icmp \
    src-address=192.168.11.252
```

On both routers I matched ICMP type 8 (echo request) to rule:

```
add action=accept chain=forward dst-address=192.168.11.252 protocol=icmp \
    src-address=192.168.100.17
```

Complete rules on both routers:

```
add action=accept chain=forward dst-address=192.168.100.17 icmp-options=0:0-255 \
    protocol=icmp src-address=192.168.11.252
add action=accept chain=forward dst-address=192.168.11.252 icmp-options=8:0-255 \
    protocol=icmp src-address=192.168.100.17
add action=drop chain=forward
```

So from 192.168.100.17 to 192.168.11.252 - ping is working.

From 192.168.11.252 to 192.168.100.17 - ping is not working.